# How to render img with Phoenix?

Tags: templates, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm new in phoenix. I need to display all the posts and pictures to them on the main page. I written below code in my index template:

`<img src="<%= Blog.Image.url({@post.image, @post}, signed: true) %>">`

And i got this

`lib/blog_web/templates/post/index.html.heex:19:21: expected closing` " `for attribute value`

What i missing?

Comment: Remove the unmatched quote `"` (right after closing `%>`.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't fully paste my code from template. I update it

Comment: Do `IO.inspect(Blog.Image.url({@post.image, @post}, signed: true))` somewhere outside tags and examine it, looks like it contains a quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [HEEx documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.Helpers.html#sigil_H/2-heex-extension-defining-attributes) notes:

> ...code interpolation using `<%= ... %>` and `<% ... %>` are restricted to the body (inner content) of the HTML/component nodes and it cannot be applied within tags.

Instead, there is specific HEEx syntax `attribute={expression}` for interpolating attribute values.  In your example, you'd use

```html
<img src={Blog.Image.url({@post.image, @post}, signed: true)}>
```

The engine will correctly insert quotation marks and other escaping as required (or, if `Blog.Image.url/2` returns `nil`, omit the attribute entirely).

Comment: Thank you very much, only today I noticed that Vs code also highlighted this to me. But I used /> in the closing tag and the picture was not displayed, but with your option everything worked